# Using redirection in C for file input?

Tags: c, file, command-line-arguments

I need to read a file from the terminal and make changes in it. The command will look like:
`./a.out x y 2 3 4 5 <inputFile`
Where `x y 2 3 4 5` are command line arguments for the program and `<inputFile` is the file to be read from.
I'm unable to understand how to use fgets() to open inputFile automatically into my program.
*Note: The input file is subject to change on the command line so I am unable to use fopen()*

Comment: When you do `executable ... <input.file`, your program (before `main()` even starts) associates `stdin` with the input file, opened in text mode and automatically closed when the program terminates. Likewise for `executable ... >output.file` associates `stdout` with output file. You can mix the two ... `executable ... <input.file >output.file`

Comment: Is it a requirement that you shouldn't use fopen ? 

Because if not, you should be able to solve your problem with it. 
In your program the main can be declared like this : 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) ;
So you should be able to check each argument, detect and open the file.
And whether or not the input file change, you should be fine since fopen takes the filename and you will take it from argv.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read up on the concept of standard io (aka stdio), and how the standard file streams `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` relate to shell redirection.

*Since this is for homework, I'm not giving a full solution. Doing the legwork of actually figuring out yourself how this stuff works, is why (we) TAs give exercises like that. Stuff you learn this way, will stick better.*

Comment: the point of the question was not to gain a full solution just a better understanding on how fgets() would work as I've been looking around and wasn't able to understand it. Thanks though! :)